# Draw a line and rectangle using mouse events in pyqt

Tags: qt, pyqt

i want to develop an application to draw a line and rectangle as one can draw in ms paint...
keeping one point fixed .
can anyone help with any example...

Comment: This is very general.  Can you narrow down what area you're having trouble with specifically?

Answer (score 2):

You'll find a lot of convenience functions in [QPainter](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qpainter.html), such as drawRect.

Use QWidget::mousePressEvent, QWidget::mouseMoveEvent and QWidget::mouseReleaseEvent to know where the user is drawing the shape.

You should have a QImage for the shapes that have already been drawn.
While the user is creating a new shape, you'll need to add that to the QPixmap that is shown to the user, but don't add the new shape to the QImage until the user releases the mouse button.  That way you can adjust the shape that they're drawing as they draw it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose looking into the [scribble example](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/widgets-scribble.html) will get us the exact solution.
I also wanted the same thing to be done - so I copied the relevant code from the scribble example and made some changes to make it work the way I want.

Although this question was asked years ago - still if any one needs the code - I 'll help.

Comment: scribble is good for drawing lines, but is horrible if you want to drawn a rectangle.  Is this what you do in your code?

Comment: @Goddard: I don't understand what you're trying to say. Are you mocking me or asking me for some explanation?? Please elaborate.